# Querying the last inserted data in SQL with huge data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this profile table with object id which is primary. I am using a script to import lacks of users into the profile table. For convenience I am tracking the object id range which is getting inserted in the table. The problem is the data gets inserted in random manner and I am not able to track which was the last object id inserted.
I have tried

```
select * from managed_profile order by objectid desc limit 1,1;
```

The issue with this is it is giving the last data inserted.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could add column with timestamp and use it in your SQL to order it by time?

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) if you tagged your question properly